# Confused about building OpenStack Packages?

Tags: package-management, packaging, openstack

I found OpenStack build task on Ubuntu QA site, but I am a little confused about the build steps.

Here's the link for build steps: https://jenkins.qa.ubuntu.com/view/Openstack_Testing/view/Grizzly/job/precise_grizzly_keystone_stable/275/consoleText

From the jenkins build log, I know the steps how Ubuntu build a Openstack packages:

1. get openstack code from github, use `git clone`
2. build `openstack tar.gz` file using `python setup.py sdist`
3. use `bzr` to get the debian control files which is maintenance by canonical
4. use `dch` command to generate a new build release and commit it to local
5. use `bzr builddeb -S -- -sa -us -uc` to generate source package and related control file, such like `dsc`
6. sign the package
7. use `mk-build-deps` to install dependency
8. use `sbuild` to generate the real deb packages
9. upload to testing repos

My questions is:

1. In step 5, we already can generate the deb packages without `-S`, but why we finally use `sbuild` to generate it? Is this only for signature?
2. What's the difference between `bzr builddeb` and `sbuild`?
3. I found the build scripts which jenkins used is located here: `~openstack-ubuntu-testing/openstack-ubuntu-testing`, but when I try to run any commands under `bin`, I always get:

   ```
   root@demo:~/openstack-ubuntu-testing/bin# ./build-package
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "./build-package", line 14, in <module>
       from openstack_ubuntu_testing.build.component_build import ComponentBuild
     File "/home/sysadmin/openstack-ubuntu-testing/bin/openstack_ubuntu_testing/build/component_build.py", line 11, in <module>
       from schroot.executor import SchrootExecutor
   ImportError: No module named schroot.executor
   ```

I tried to use pip to install schroot, but it seems they don't have a executor in it.

Please help.

Comment: I've opened the link you've provided and got this error text: HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /view/Openstack_Testing/view/Grizzly/job/precise_grizzly_keystone_stable/275/consoleText. Reason:

    Not Found
Powered by Jetty://

Comment: a similar link as he provided is https://jenkins.qa.ubuntu.com/view/Openstack_Testing/view/Grizzly/job/precise_grizzly_keystone_stable/284/consoleText

Answer (score 1):

`sbuild` builds a package in an isolated environment using `schroot`. In this environment, only the build dependencies declared by the source package are installed, and nothing else. This helps ensure that the build isn't influenced by the developer or CI environment it is run from. For example, without sbuild, the presence of a package in the CI environment might make it appear that the build succeeds when in fact it was an undeclared build dependency and so fails everywhere else. For reproducibility and stability reasons, it is better to use sbuild.